# Windows Phone Background Agent Read Tile Query String

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is there any way to read the query string of a tile in a Windows Phone Background agent. Navigation Context doesn't seem to work.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerate all tiles of the app and you'll be able to check the URIs and query strings: [ShellTile.ActiveTiles Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.shelltile.activetiles%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Yes I already did that except there is no method to check the query string from the background agent

Comment: Check the [NavigationUri property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.shelltile(v=vs.105).aspx) of the enumerated tiles.

Comment: Yes but there is no way to get the query string from the NavigationUri property

Comment: Why? `Property Value
Type: System.Uri
The URI and launch parameter this is navigated to when a secondary Tile is tapped.`